# Why is the Value undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value of this span from a website.

```
<span class="part middle-block">78</span>
```

If I do this with this command it will return `undefined`.

```
$(".user-coins-container .coins-component .part.middle-block").html;
```

Comment: Is your selector correct? Is your span already created?

Comment: I don't see any value. what I see is a person not knowing what "value" means..

Comment: `html()` is a function, not property

Comment: `document.querySelector('.part.middle-block').textContent` you're welcome

Comment: thanks vsync this works. And yes im a new programmer i still learning.

Comment: impossible to help since we do not know the HTML structure and what `.user-coins-container .coins-component` applies too

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by:

```
$(".middle-block").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `span` has two classes, `part` and `middle-block`, you'll need the selector `.part.middle-block`. Then, use the `.text()` jQuery function to get the value of the `span`. Example:

```js
var value = $(".part.middle-block").text();
console.log("Value:", value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="part middle-block">78</span>
```

Comment: If i do this the console return TypeError: $(...).text is not a function

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Comment: The website is not mine but i try other jQuery commands and they will work. 
For example if i want to change the innerhtml of an span or div.

Comment: But i have the right answer 
document.querySelector('.part.middle-block').textContent

Answer (score 0):

First include jquery inside your project and link it in the html file properly and then:

```
$('.part.middle-block').text()
```

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/mayurdandekar/w3zv618a/

Answer (score -2):

You can put an `id` and then get by `#id` and use `html()`, not `html`!